# All classpath variables do not show command line

Tags: mysql, svn, classpath, collabnet

I know how to set classpath in windows **(***Start ==> Control Panel ==> Administrative Tools ==>
      Computer Management ==> Right click on Computer Management
               (Local) ==> Select Properties ==> Click on Advanced Tab ==>
                Click on Environmental Variables Settings button***)**.
I have already done it, but when I run **echo %path%** , **MySql** and **CollabNet Subversion** don't show in variables returned. Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Start the command window again. Changes to the env variables only apply to *new* processes, not to existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using `classpath` in lower caps, it should be `CLASSPATH`.